# How to show a list of checkbox from the base in ASP MVC and Javascript

Tags: c#, jquery, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-3

I am developing an ASP .Net MVC 3 application using C# and SQL Server 2005.

I am using also Entity Framework and Code First Method.

My problem is to display a list of `checkbox` of values which are loadinf from a table in the base.

The list of checkbox depends on the value of the item selected in a DropDownList.

I try to do this using Javascript :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.post("/ProfileGa/Application", { term: "" + $("#Txt").val() + "SelectedGenre" }, 
function (html)
{
//construct check boxes with this data elements.
  $('#resultDiv').append("<input type='checkbox' id='checkbox" + html[i].Id + "'" + "/>" + html[i].title);
}
</script>
```

This is the View :

```
<div>
         <%:Html.Label("Type :")%><%: Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedGenre, Model.GenreItems)%>

   </div>

   <table border = "transparent">
    <tr>
        <th>

        </th>

        </tr>

        <% foreach (var item in Model.FaItems) { %>
    <tr>
         <td>

            <%: Html:CheckBoxFor (modelItem => item.Nom_Famille) %>
        </td>


    </tr>
     <% } %>

    </table>
```

and this is the Controller :

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Application(Genre genre)
        {
            var vv = new FlowViewModel();

            vv.GenreItems = new SelectList(db.Genres.ToList(), "ID_G", "ID_G");


            if (vv.SelectedGenre == "Famille")
            {

                vv.FaItems = db.Familles.ToList();


            }
            else if (vv.SelectedGenre == "Sous Famille")
            {
                vv.SFItems = db.Sous_Familles.ToList();

            }
            return View(vv);

        }
```

and this is the model :

```
public class FlowViewModel
{

    [Key]
    public string IDv { get; set; }

    public List<Famille> FaItems { get; set; }
    public List<Sous_Famille> SFItems { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public SelectList GenreItems { get; set; }
    public string SelectedGenre { get; set; } 

    public FlowViewModel()
    {
        FaItems = new List<Famille>();
        SFItems = new List<Sous_Famille>();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is being returned from /ProfileGa/Application POST call? A JSON string, array?

Comment: It is a string of the selected value in the checkbox

Comment: I think he means what does the server return. In other words, in your callback what is the value of the `html`-variable. Apart from that, do you have any errors in the console, what is currently happening?

Comment: @Kenneth I really don't know the value of html. 
It's a javascript code that I put in the view and I can't put a breakpoint in the view to know the value.
About the error, No I don't habe anyone

Comment: You should open your developer tools (firebug in firefox, chrome dev tools in chrom (F12)), put a breakpoint on that line and inspect the value

Comment: @Kenneth yes I thought in this idea but as I said in the comment above. I can't debug in the view,,,is there any other solution ?

Comment: Yes, you can. It's javascript, it runs in a browser. If it runs in a browser you can debug it

Comment: yes,,i did it,,,hold on i will give you the result

Comment: @Kenneth the problem that I can't hit the breakpoint ! I open the page and I change the value of DropDownList and nothing happened !